# Angular component host always having a border

Tags: angular, border, host

I've a simple Angular component `<app-mybutton>`.
All is ok til i make the button with round corners, by setting css `border-radius: 3rem;`.
The round corners reveal that button host ( i.e. `<app-mybutton>`) has a border.
This border business occurs in Chrome but not Firefox.
I've tried various ways to make border go away, but to no avail.
I have tried the following --
(1) mybutton.component.css ... `:host { border: none !important; outline: none !important;}`

Or

(2a) mybutton.component.ts ...
In @Component({...}), add the line `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None;`
(2b) app.component.html ...
`<div class="btn-holder"><app-mybutton></app-mybutton></div>`
(2b) styles.css ...`.btn-holder > * { border: none !important; outline: none !important;}`

But both ways above failed to remove the mysterious host border.
Is border thing an Angular (ver7 i am using) or Chrome issue?
Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click > inspect the element in chrome, dev tools will open up. Two sub-windows will be open, one with an elements tab and styles in the other. If you select  in the elements window, then look at the styles window, it should reveal where the button is getting this border from.

Comment: hi, tks for the reply.

Comment: I think i have figured out the cause of that weird border... i took bootstrap out of the css, and that weird border is no more! I am now zooming in to bootstrap to figure out ...  tks for ur prompt response nonetheless!

Comment: ... finally, after lots of grueling, painstaking detective work, it turns out the cause of mysterious :host border was due to ... using variable named type in mybutton.component.html and mybutton.component.ts, as shown below.
 --- mybutton.component.html 
<app-mybutton [type]="'submit'"></app-mybutton>

 --- mybutton.component.ts 
@Input() type = 'button';

Answer (score 1):

... finally, after lots of grueling, painstaking detective work, it turns out the cause of mysterious :host border (impossible to eradicate!) was due to ... using variable named type in mybutton.component.html and mybutton.component.ts, as shown below.
 --- `mybutton.component.html`
`<app-mybutton [type]="'submit'"></app-mybutton>`

--- `mybutton.component.ts`
 `@Input() type = 'button';`

Must say to give myself a pat on the back.